# Fine tune Sentiment Analysis of Amazon Comprehent

Tags: amazon-web-services, sentiment-analysis, amazon-comprehend, fine-tuning

I got a pretty short question: Is it possible to fine tune the Amazon Comprehend Sentiment Analyzer? I cannot find anythin on the internet, but it somehow feels weird that its not possible.

Cheers